# Splitting bits in Java

Tags: java, bit

I want to split 16 bits into two 8 bit sections, but I can not think an idea how to do it.

Ex. `1111111000011111`

Output: `11111110` and `00011111`

Here's my code so far:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()){

        bin = scan.nextLine();
        String[] memory = new String[] bin.length()/8;
        for (int i = 0; i < memory.length; i++){
            memory[i] = bin.substring(i*8, i*8 + 8);
        }
```

but its error.

Comment: What are these bits stored in?  An `int`? A `char`?

Comment: Actually I will get a value on a textfile.

Comment: I posted my code, but its error

Comment: @user6051183 what kind of error do you get?

Comment: It says, missing an array dimension and an illegal start of expression.

Comment: Thankyou. theres no error, but how I gonna print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating an array, you have to specify the size inside the brackets, so replace:
`String[] memory = new String[] bin.length()/8;`, by
`String[] memory = new String[bin.length()/8];`

Comment: @user6051183 print it to where?

Comment: In console. Or by system.out println();

Comment: @user6051183, you could do it inside the main loop, by adding `System.out.println(memory[i])` at the end of the loop body. Or start a new loop after you finished populating your `memory` array

Comment: Thankyou, last Question. what if I have '1000010100000011' is it possible that I will get an output of 00000011 and 10000101 instead of 10000101 and 00000011?

Comment: The way your code is, it will get the bytes from left to right, so you would get 10000101 and 00000011. If you want the order to change, you could code that in

Comment: Yeah because I dont have an idea how to reverse it  by the way can i store it on array of 256 items of sting of length 8? I cant understand it.

Comment: Hahaha. yeah, im confused becuase 1 byte is equal to 8bits. But, 256. Well ;)